# JavaScript create input problems

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I found [this JavaScript](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/dynamic-add-textbox-input-button-radio-element-html-javascript.html) online that adds input buttons when you press a button.

I changed it so that instead of being able to select which type of input you create it just automatically creates a textbox. But it's not working. What should I change?

```
function add(type) {

  //Create an input type dynamically.
  var element = document.createElement("input");

  //Assign different attributes to the element.
  element.setAttribute("type", "text");
  element.setAttribute("name", "goal[]");

  var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

  //Append the element in page (in span).
  foo.appendChild(element);

}

<INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value)"/>

<span id="fooBar">&nbsp;</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Fa8Z/)

Your add function is correct, but I think something is broken here—`document.forms[0].element.value`

```
onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value)"
```

Try changing it to

```
onclick="add()"
```

Since you're not using that type parameter anyway

Comment: How would I also add a line break after each input so they rendered below each other?

Comment: I think you'd want to do: `document.createElement("br");` and insert it where you want the line break

Comment: Would I put it in the function add()? That didn't work. Should I put it with the onclick along with add?

Comment: You should be able to add the br like you did with the input - here's an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4Fa8Z/2/

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers do not allow to set the `name` attribute dynamically on an element.

You can specify the `name` attribute in the markup passed to `createElement()` to work around this problem:

```
var element = document.createElement("<input name='goal[]' type='text' />");
```